# AWS errors LimitExceededException and EntityAlreadyExistsException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been having problem deploying my python project unto aws
It has been giving me the error `NotAuthorizedError: Operation Denied. Access Denied`
But on getting into amazon I saw these errors. These are just the summary

```
{"Records":[
{"eventName":"AddRoleToInstanceProfile",
"errorCode":"LimitExceededException",
"errorMessage":"Cannot exceed quota for InstanceSessionsPerInstanceProfile: 1",
"requestParameters":{
    "instanceProfileName":"aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role",
    "roleName":"aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"}},
{"eventName":"CreateRole",
"errorCode":"EntityAlreadyExistsException",
"errorMessage":"Role with name aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role already exists.",
"requestParameters":{"roleName":"aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role",}},
{"eventName":"CreateInstanceProfile",
"errorCode":"EntityAlreadyExistsException",
"errorMessage":"Instance Profile aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role already exists."}]}
```

Please how can i overcome this problems since I am doing it programmatically through ebcli and I am not creating it manually
Any help would be appreciated